# Draw line on the desktop with clickable around line

Tags: java, swing, draw

I want create a program that draw line on desktop with this property that user can click on desktop icons near the line.
I create sample. I create transparent frame and draw jWindow on this. in MouseReleased event dispose main frame then stay all jwindows that created. My code create many number of jwindow and this is very bad. For draw line 30cm program create over than 400 jwindow and this causes os be very heavy.
Can help me anybody?
(Excuse me for my ugly english)

```
    package PKHMain;

    import java.awt.Color;
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JWindow;

public class FRMMain extends JFrame implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

    public FRMMain() {
        this.setUndecorated(true);
        this.setSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().width, Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().height);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        this.setVisible(true);
        addMouseListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new FRMMain();
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
        this.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {
        int x = event.getX();
        int y = event.getY();
        JWindow frame = new JWindow();
        frame.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
        frame.setContentPane(new ShapedPane(x, y));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocation(x, y);
        frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event) {
    }

    public class ShapedPane extends JPanel {

        public int x1;
        public int y1;

        public ShapedPane(int x, int y) {
            setOpaque(false);
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            x1 = x;
            y1 = y;
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(5, 5);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            RenderingHints hints = new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g2.setRenderingHints(hints);
            g2.setColor(Color.red);
            g2.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight()));
            g2.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: my question and quite important for you is for why reason is painting in paint() with repaint() which can caused hight procesor consuption or endless loop

Comment: I remove paint() method and not change any things.

Comment: Put a list of shapes into your `FRMMain` class and draw these shapes inside the `paint` method of that `FRMMain` frame and don’t create any new window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are touching system specific behavior with your program, e.g. on my machine the program will not receive any mouse event at all as the background color has an alpha value of zero. Setting it to at least one makes it receiving clicks and drags. So this is a way to control the desired click-through behavior but it might be the case that it doesn’t work for you.

Here is the program as it work on my machine (Java 7 and Windows 7):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class FRMMain extends JFrame {
  private final List<Shape> list=new ArrayList<>();
  private boolean paintPhase=true;

  public FRMMain() {
      this.setUndecorated(true);
      final Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
      this.setSize(screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
      this.setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      this.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 1));
      this.setOpacity(1f);
      this.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
      this.setVisible(true);
      enableEvents(AWTEvent.MOUSE_EVENT_MASK|AWTEvent.MOUSE_MOTION_EVENT_MASK);
  }
  @Override
  protected void processMouseEvent(MouseEvent e) {
    if(paintPhase && e.getID()==MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED) {
      paintPhase = false;
      // on my machine the following line is enough to enable click-through
      setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
      // but if this doesn’t work, the following should do:
      Area area=new Area();
      BasicStroke b=new BasicStroke(2f);
      for(Shape s:list) area.add(new Area(b.createStrokedShape(s)));
      setShape(area);
    }
    super.processMouseEvent(e);
  }
  @Override
  protected void processMouseMotionEvent(MouseEvent event)
  {
    if(paintPhase && event.getID()==MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED) {
      int x = event.getX();
      int y = event.getY();
      list.add(new Ellipse2D.Float(x, y, 8, 8));
      repaint();
    }
    super.processMouseMotionEvent(event);
  }
  @Override
  public boolean contains(int x, int y) {
    return paintPhase;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      new FRMMain();
  }

  @Override
  public void paint(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D gfx=(Graphics2D)g;
    gfx.setColor(Color.RED);
    for(Shape s:list) gfx.draw(s);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Holger. Thanks for replay.

Comment: Hi Holger. Thanks for replay. I can draw line with mouse event. i need program that i can draw line on screen and after draw line all objects on screen will be available(icons, text, ...). at your program the transparent layer stay on screen! i need after draw line the line alone stay on desktop.

Comment: As said, on my machine it works as intended as setting the background alpha to zero on mouse release will enable the click-through transparency. If that doesn’t work for you you could try to use `setShape` on the window with a compound shape of all shapes of the list. Ok, I updated the answer to show how to do it. Look at the `processMouseEvent` method…

Comment: Thank you my friend. It work very well. i changed very small of your code and everything work very well. Thanks.

Comment: @Holger again code from stone_edge :-), caused by paint() to Top-Level Container, put there JPanel and to override paintComponent(), call super.paintComponent() in the case that you don't want to cumulating a painting, +1 interesting idea to use AWTEventListener instead of two separates Mouse & MouseMotionListener

Comment: @mKorbel: it does not use `AWTEventListener` it just overrides the components event processing methods which are also responsible for invoking the registered listeners, if any. I would never register a component on itself as a listener, that feels a bit strange to me, and may cause bugs when done in the constructor and there are subclasses. In most cases if a component deals with its own events it wants to have the control over whether its actions take place before notifying listeners or after, so overriding the `process…Event` methods is the way to go then.

Comment: can u guyz tell me how can we do this using python..?

Comment: @Jerin A Mathews: don’t ask new questions in the comments. You can [open a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and may add a link to this question if you think it helps…