# JAVA - Get mouse location when mouse is clicked

Tags: java, mouseevent

I need to get the absolute location of mouse after a click on the screen. I've already searched on the web but the only solution I have found uses this method:

```
MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation()
```

which gets the position independently from the click.

Otherwise, i have to use an `EventListener` to check out when the mouse is clicked, but the problem is that listeners are related to a component, while i need the absolute location.

How can i solve this?

Comment: You'll need to translate the relative position related to the component to absolute coordinates

Comment: the problem is that i don't have a component, because i need to get the coordinates of a point on the screen (in particular on a browser window)

Comment: You can create a transparent window covering the region you are interested in and intercepting mouse clicks. Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20118196/2711488) helps.

Answer (score 2):

This is an OS dependent feature. As far as I understand your question, you don't have a GUI or you don't want to add a listener to your GUI components. JVM will only receive clicks for components that are related to it.

Here you have to write some native code to hook to events that you want on your own, or you should use a library like [jnativehook](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook) that does the same thing for you and you don't need to write code for Linux, Mac OS X and Windows.